# PyQt5 - Ignoring widgets within QGraphicsView when dragging and dropping

Tags: python, pyqt5, drag-and-drop, qgraphicsview

I have a test PyQt application with a QGraphicsView/Scene, and a toolbar with a button in it which allows one to drag a shape into the viewport.

There's also another button in the middle of the viewport (in my real application this is a number of icons and labels, imagine something like the icons overlaid at the top of unreal engine viewport UI).

[image: 923e2b9e-3b15-4dca-b1ec-9904e10d9bba-image.png]

When dragging a shape from the toolbar into the viewport, if somebody mouses over the button embedded in the viewport, it triggers a 'dragLeaveEvent' method, where I actually want to ignore this button entirely, letting me continue to drag the shape around the viewport.

I have tried various things, including handling the dragging and dropping from the scene, from the view, and setting event.ignore() on the default drag/drop methods in various places. If I ignore events on the QGraphicsView, then I can't drag/drop on the scene either. It seems whatever's on top will decide what the drag/drop functionality will be. I really want to be able to ignore the top level widget (the viewport button).

Here is minimal code for the issue. If you drag the 'circle' from the toolbar onto the viewport, and hover over the viewport button, the circle will drop to the scene, and a new one will be created. This is not the behaviour I'm looking for. I want to be able to ignore the viewport button and continue to drag the object around.

Any advice would be most appreciated!

Cheers,
Ekar

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem, QToolBar, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel, QGraphicsEllipseItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData, QRectF, QPointF


class CircleItem(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # create a simple shape we can move around the scene
        self.shape = QGraphicsEllipseItem(x, y, radius, radius)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(self.shape.boundingRect())

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        self.shape.paint(painter, option, widget)


# for toolbar icons
class DragDropWidget(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, shape_type):
        super().__init__(shape_type)

        self.shape_type = shape_type

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        drag = QDrag(self)
        drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
        mime_data = QMimeData()
        mime_data.setText(self.shape_type)
        drag.setMimeData(mime_data)
        drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)


class CustomView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, scene):
        super(CustomView, self).__init__(scene)

    # def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
    #     event.ignore()
        
    # def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
    #     event.ignore()

    # def dropEvent(self, event):
    #     event.ignore()

    # def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
    #     event.ignore()


class CustomScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomScene, self).__init__()

        self.shape = None

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            # Create the shape and add to scene
            shape_type = event.mimeData().text()
            self.shape = CircleItem(0, 0, 100)
            self.addItem(self.shape)

        event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.shape:
            # Move the shape around the scene with mouse cursor
            self.shape.setPos(event.scenePos())

        event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        # Drop the shape to the scene
        self.shape = None
        event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        # I don't want this event to be tiggered when mousing over button in viewport
        print("LEAVING!")
        #event.acceptProposedAction()




class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.scene = CustomScene()
        self.view = CustomView(self.scene)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

        toolbar = QToolBar("Shapes Toolbar")
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)

        circle_button = DragDropWidget('Circle')
        toolbar.addWidget(circle_button)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        main_widget = QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)

        # UI for the view
        view_button = QPushButton('I want to ignore this button when drag/dropping')
        view_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        view_layout.addWidget(view_button)
        self.view.setLayout(view_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'd start by not adding alien widgets to scroll areas (especially a Graphics View) unless you know how to deal with them, as they have an internal layout and geometry management that should be handled with *extreme* care (and awareness). Besides, there's little you can do for this specific situation, because dragLeave is caused by the viewport being left, which is a *sibling* of the button. You should at least try to add it to the viewport instead, but I'd still be careful about this approach. Besides, if you want to detect *real* drag leave events, you should do it in the view, not the scene.

Comment: Yes, thankyou- seems the question I should be asking is what is the correct way to add labels/buttons to the main viewport. In my actual case, I have a QStackedWidget which allows alternating between different viewports (which allow mouse panning/zooming). I'm a bit confused about whether buttons could/should be added to the graphicsScene, graphicsView, or the main stacked widget. I have the scrollbars disabled in the QGraphicsView. 

Another thought is to drop objects as soon as they enter the viewport, and continue setting their position on mouseMoveEvent in the GraphicsView.

Comment: Well, as said, if you want to add widgets to the viewport, you have to *actually* add them to the viewport. Like all Qt scroll areas, QGraphicsView is based on QAbstractScrollArea, a complex widget made of many child widgets (like the scroll bars) and, most importantly, a viewport widget, which is where the scroll contents are actually shown. That is accessible through `viewport()`, and, in fact, your code above will work as you want if you set the layout for it: `self.view.viewport().setLayout(view_layout)`. A better choice, though, would be a container widget set as child of the viewport.

Comment: Thanks again, Musicamante. Yes, setting `self.view.viewport().setLayout(view_layout)` works fine, and I've done what you've suggested- creating a container widget as child of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating my answer here based on musicamante's latest comment, which advises not to set a layout on the viewport, but to create the 'viewport_controls' with the viewport as parent, and then handle the resizing from the parent widget. I have cut down the code to a more simplified example.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QToolBar, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel


class ViewportControls(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QPushButton('Do something')
        self.button2 = QPushButton('Do something else')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button2)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

        toolbar = QToolBar("Shapes Toolbar")
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)

        circle_button = QLabel('Circle')
        toolbar.addWidget(circle_button)

        self.viewport_controls = ViewportControls(self.view.viewport())

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        new_size = self.size()  # Get the new size of the widget
        self.viewport_controls.setGeometry(0, 0, new_size.width(), new_size.height())
        super().resizeEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You should still avoid to set a layout on the viewport too. Complex widgets do not (nor should) have an exposed layout and for good reasons: most importantly, the viewport should never have a layout, because setting one on it may alter some of its basic behavior that shouldn't affect the overall behavior. Just create the `ViewportControls()` with the viewport as parent (add a proper argument to `__init__`), then, if you need to update the geometry of the "embedded toolbar" whenever the view is resized, do it within the `resizeEvent()` and manually set the geometry based on the new size.

Comment: Thanks again, musicamante- I've updated the code. Does this look better?